# how to add a view from iphone static library without passing self.view as a a parameter?

Tags: iphone, ios5, static-libraries, xcode4.3

I am new to his iphone development.I would like to know whether there is any method to add a view to the self.view without passing it as a parameter.Can any one suggest me a method to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Its simple. A parameter is nothing but a reference to it. So if you have a reference to it then you can. So declare a reference to the view which you want to add as a subview.
Then in the method you can just call the methods `[self.view addSubView:<object>.referencedView];`

Comment: i want to do this adding from the library .Then how should i do it?

Answer (score 0):

No,its not possible. If you want to add a view to self.view, you will have to pass it as an argument.

If you do not want to pass then your library should have knowledge of your viewController and it should add subview to viewController.view.

Comment: how to get the information of the viewcontroller from library?